# How to model transitive joins over multiple tables in JPA

Tags: jpa

In our EE6 / JPA project we are using entity classes with mapped relationship quite extensively. All is well when modelling fields in "neighboring" tables, i.e. direct PK/FK relationships, even with composite keys. We also have some many-to-many relationships using join tables that are mapped neatly in the entities.

But I can't wrap my head around the following situation:

[image: simple DB model requiring multiple joins]

Let's assume I have books of different categories, and authors that can be attached to the books. Now imagine that I wanted to "boost" certain authors in certain categories.

Now, given a book, I could e.g. emphasize certain authors.

In an SQL (or, I guess JPQL) query, it would be quite trivial to use JOINs to get a list of authors and their boost factors. (Or even only for a given author on a given book, show that factor.)

But in JPA? I have no idea.

I've tried something like this in `BookAuthor.java`...

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
              @JoinColumn(name = "AID", referencedColumnName = "AID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
              @JoinColumn(name = "CID", referencedColumnName = "CID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
private Boost boost;
```

...but obviously JPA has no idea where to find "CID".

My current workaround is having a little transient method that first fetches all boost factors per book and then returns only the one that fits the current author.

```
@Transient
public Boost getBoost() {
    Set<Boost> boosts = this.getBook().getCategory().getBoosts();
    for (Boost elem : boosts) {
        if (elem.getAuthor().equals(this.author))
        return elem;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But that can't be right, can it?

Comment: For the record, I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697703/jpa-3-way-join-annotation) which seems incredibly relevant, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to have a boost object on your book_author object?  You could have a finder "findByBookAuthor" on your boost retrieval service that uses the jpql:

```
Select b FROM Boost b join Category c join Book bk where bk.BID = :BID AND c.CID = bk.CID AND b.AID = :AID
```

Comment: I'd much like to avoid sending a query because that means that I need to access the entity manager. Style-wise, in terms of separation-of-concerns, I don't want either the entity object nor the calling service to directly talk to the database.